# [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0] while get textvalue

Tags: ios, tags, uibutton, uitextview

I have `UIWebView` for displays HTML pages. When longpress on webview i'm getting x & y coordinates save to database. In `UIMenuItem`, click note button, it display the `UITextView` for write notes. If click Done button it store to database with x & y coordinates. Then display the one button with `Tag` on x & y coordinates for each touchable coordinates with text. Later if i click the button the tag will match with coordinates i need to displays the text from database. But i'm  getting error

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

NSMutableArray *items = [[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] menuItems] mutableCopy];
    if (!items) items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIMenuItem *menuItem;
    menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"BookMark" action:@selector(book:)];
    [items addObject:menuItem];
    [menuItem release];
    menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notes" action:@selector(note:)];
    [items addObject:menuItem];
    [menuItem release];

    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:items];


    [items release];


    tap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapTest:)];
    [tap setDelegate:self];


    [wbCont.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}
```

Long press getting coordinates save:

```
- (void)tapTest:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"coordinate is %f %f", [sender locationInView:wbCont.scrollView].x, [sender locationInView:wbCont.scrollView].y);


     xcor = [sender locationInView:wbCont.scrollView].x;
     ycor = [sender locationInView:wbCont.scrollView].y;


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"filepath %@",path);


    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {



        const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT xcoor FROM touch where xcoor = '%f' AND ycoor = '%f' AND artt_id='%@'",xcor,ycor,artID] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

        BOOL favExist = false;

        sqlite3_stmt *statement, *addStmt;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {



                favExist = true;
            }
        }


        if(!favExist){



            const char *sqlInsert = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into touch (xcoor,ycoor,artt_id) values ('%f','%f','%@')", xcor,ycor,artID] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSLog(@"sql insert is %s",sqlInsert);


            // [catID release];

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlInsert, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

            NSLog(@"error is %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));

            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));


        }else {


        }

    }

}
```

click note on UIMenuItem:

```
- (void)note:(id)sender   {

    NSLog(@"Note");


    txtview = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,568)];

    txtview.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
    txtview.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    txtview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    txtview.scrollEnabled = YES;
    txtview.pagingEnabled = YES;
    txtview.editable = YES;
     txtview.tag = mainTag*10000;




    [self.view addSubview:txtview];


 button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(done:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(240.0, 20.0, 60.0, 40.0);
    [txtview addSubview:button];



}
```

click done button after writing text in UITextView save to database textnote table with x & y coordinates then displays webviewbutton on x & y coordinates:

```
-(void)done:(id)sender  {


    NSLog(@"done");


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:1];

    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ohs.sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"filepath %@",path);


    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {



        const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT textnotes,text_id,txcoor,tycoor FROM textnote where textnotes = '%@' AND text_id = '%@' AND txcoor = '%f' AND tycoor = '%f'",txtview.text,artID,xcor,ycor] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

        BOOL favExist = false;

        sqlite3_stmt *statement, *addStmt;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


                favExist = true;
            }
        }


        if(!favExist){


            const char *sqlInsert = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into textnote (textnotes,text_id,txcoor,tycoor ) values ('%@','%@','%f','%f')", txtview.text,artID,xcor,ycor] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSLog(@"sql insert is %s",sqlInsert);

            // [catID release];

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlInsert, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));



        }else {



        }

    }



    NSArray *coorpaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *coordocumentsDirectory = [coorpaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"docs dir is %@", coordocumentsDirectory);

    NSString *coorpath = [coordocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ohs.sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"filepath %@",coorpath);

    if (sqlite3_open([coorpath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {


        const char *sql =  [[NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"SELECT xcoor,ycoor,artt_id FROM touch where artt_id = %@", artID]cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        NSLog(@"getmainsql is %s",sql);

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {



                table_touch_xcor=sqlite3_column_double(statement, 0);

                table_touch_ycor=sqlite3_column_double(statement, 1);

                table_touch_artid = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2);

                if(table_touch_xcor && table_touch_ycor && table_touch_artid){



                    NSArray *coorpaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                    NSString *coordocumentsDirectory = [coorpaths objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSLog(@"docs dir is %@", coordocumentsDirectory);

                    NSString *coorpath = [coordocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ohs.sqlite"];
                    NSLog(@"filepath %@",coorpath);

                    if (sqlite3_open([coorpath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {



                        const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT textnotes,text_id,txcoor,tycoor FROM textnote where  text_id = '%@' AND txcoor = '%f' AND tycoor = '%f'",artID,table_touch_xcor,table_touch_ycor] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                        NSLog(@"getmainsql is %s",sql);

                        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

                        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
                            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {




                                txtstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                             (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];


                                table_textnote_artid = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);


                                table_textnote_xcor=sqlite3_column_double(statement, 2);

                                table_textnote_ycor=sqlite3_column_double(statement, 3);



                                if(table_textnote_xcor && table_textnote_ycor && table_textnote_artid ){


                                    webviewbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

                                    [webviewbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(webviewbuttonclick1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                                    [webviewbutton setTitle:@"click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                                    webviewbutton.frame = CGRectMake(table_textnote_xcor, table_textnote_ycor, 30.0, 20.0);


                                    webviewbutton.tag = gTag;
                                    gTag++;

                                    [wbCont.scrollView  addSubview:webviewbutton];






                                }




                            }
                        }
                    }


                }



            }
        }
    }
```

Then webviewbutton click i'm getting x & y coordinates with saved text from database. Here i need to get saved text for webviewbutton tag.

```
-(void)webviewbuttonclick1:(id)sender{

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:1];

    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];



    textArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {


      //  const char *sql =  [[NSString stringWithFormat:
                           //  @"SELECT textnotes,text_id,txcoor,tycoor FROM textnote where txcoor = '%f' AND tycoor = '%f'",xcor,ycor]cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];





        const char *sql ="SELECT textnotes,text_id,txcoor,tycoor FROM textnote where txcoor = 113.0 AND tycoor = 342.0";

        NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                txtstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                             (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];


                art_Idt = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);

                tx = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 2);
                ty = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 3);

                NSLog(@"txtstring is %@",txtstring);

                NSLog(@"art_Idt is %ld",(long)art_Idt);

                NSLog(@"tx is %f",tx);
                NSLog(@"ty is %f",ty);

                [textArray addObject:txtstring];

                NSLog(@"textArray is %@",textArray);





            }
        }


    }


    txtt=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,568)];

    txtt.text=txtstring;

    NSLog(@"text is %@",txtt.text);

    [self.view addSubview:txtt];
```

Comment: I really hope you don't actually write code like this... Please use good variable names and indent the code properly. I'm not even going to try to understand your code if you don't.

Comment: Rather than using tags to identify buttons why not just use the reference to the object that you have already? And what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message `[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]` is usually shown when you're accessing elements that is greater than the size of the array.

In this case, your array only has one element, so if you want to access that element, you'll want to use `objectAtIndex:0`. Since you did not show us how you initialise/fill the array, I can't help you any more than this.

And for the love of all that's holy, please try to use better identifier names and indent your code. Nobody, no one other than you in this world would understand what `click1`, `button1`, and `button4` means. In fact in two weeks, I can assure you that you'll forget what `click1` supposed to mean. Trust me, you will quickly grow to hate programming if you keep doing this.

Comment: This is big process. I can't able to explain short. I don't know how to explain. Can you come to chat?

Comment: Is i need to store webviewbutton tag to database?